# How Can I make the height of the sidebar 100% in MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Im trying to learn MUI, and encounter this problem.

How can I make the sidebar cover in full height, I tried to do 100vh but when I scroll down and the table extends, the sidebar stops increasing. I tried 100% but it only covers the end of the list.

Is there any other way to fix this problem? or its fine cuz it's poistion is fixed?

```
const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
    <Box flex={1} height="100vh">
      <Box postion="fixed" height="100%" sx={{ boxShadow: '3' }}>
        <Box p={4}>
          <Stack
            sx={{
              display: 'flex',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}
            direction="column"
            spacing={2}
          >
            <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" />
            <Typography>Hi, DEANS</Typography>
          </Stack>
        </Box>
        <List>
          <ListItem disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton component="a" href="#home">
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Home />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Homepage" />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton component="a" href="#simple-list">
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Article />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Pages" />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton component="a" href="#simple-list">
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Group />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Groups" />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton component="a" href="#simple-list">
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Storefront />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Marketplace" />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton component="a" href="#simple-list">
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Person />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Friends" />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton component="a" href="#simple-list">
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Settings />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Settings" />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton component="a" href="#simple-list">
              <ListItemIcon>
                <AccountBox />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Profile" />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton component="a" href="#simple-list">
              <ListItemIcon>
                <ModeNight />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <Switch onChange={() => {}} />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  )
}

export default Sidebar
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you please create a jsFiddle or codepen for this problem. It will be easier to provide you solution there

Comment: Using chrome developer tools, choose the element inspector and check if there is a padding on your parent box element. That first image looks to me like there is some default MUI padding being applied. Worth investigating

Answer (score 0):

```
const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
    <Box flex={1} height="100%">
      <Box postion="fixed" height="100%" sx={{ boxShadow: '3' }}>
        <Box p={4}>
          <Stack
            sx={{
              display: 'flex',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}
            direction="column"
            spacing={2}
          >
            <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" />
            <Typography>Hi, DEANS</Typography>
          </Stack>
        </Box>
        <List>
          <ListItem disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton component="a" href="#home">
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Home />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Homepage" />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton component="a" href="#simple-list">
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Article />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Pages" />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton component="a" href="#simple-list">
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Group />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Groups" />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton component="a" href="#simple-list">
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Storefront />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Marketplace" />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton component="a" href="#simple-list">
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Person />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Friends" />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton component="a" href="#simple-list">
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Settings />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Settings" />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton component="a" href="#simple-list">
              <ListItemIcon>
                <AccountBox />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Profile" />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton component="a" href="#simple-list">
              <ListItemIcon>
                <ModeNight />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <Switch onChange={() => {}} />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  )
}

export default Sidebar
```